# Android problems with Accelerometer Class

Tags: android

I am trying to embed my accelerometer class in my secondeActivitybut i always get a cast exception 
here is my accelerometer class :

```
package com.example.lincision;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;

public class Accelerometer implements SensorEventListener {

    private float xAxis;
    private float yAxis;
    private float zAxis;
    private float lastX, lastY, lastZ;

    public float getX() {
        return this.xAxis;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return this.yAxis;
    }

    public float getZ() {
        return this.zAxis;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        // get the change of the x,y,z values of the accelerometer
        xAxis = Math.abs(lastX - event.values[0]);
        yAxis = Math.abs(lastY - event.values[1]);
        zAxis = Math.abs(lastZ - event.values[2]);

    }

}
```

here you see my secondactivity which is not working at all maybe somehas an idear what I
have to change.

```
package com.example.lincision;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.javacodegeeks.androidaccelerometerexample.R;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {



    TextView outputX;
    TextView outputY;
    TextView outputZ;

    SensorManager manager;
    Sensor accelerometer;

    SensorManager sensorManager;


    TextView currentX, currentY, currentZ;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);

    initializeViews();
    displayCleanValues();
    // display the current x,y,z accelerometer values
    displayCurrentValues();

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    accelerometer = sensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) acc,
            accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}
    Accelerometer acc = new Accelerometer();
    public void initializeViews() {
        currentX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentX);
        currentY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentY);
        currentZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentZ);

    }

    private float deltaX = acc.getX();
    private float deltaY = acc.getY();
    private float deltaZ = acc.getZ();



    public void displayCleanValues() {
        currentX.setText("0.0");
        currentY.setText("0.0");
        currentZ.setText("0.0");
    }



    // display the current x,y,z accelerometer values
    public void displayCurrentValues() {
        currentX.setText(Float.toString(deltaX));
        currentY.setText(Float.toString(deltaY));
        currentZ.setText(Float.toString(deltaZ));
    }

}
```

and here is my error message :

```
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity       ComponentInfo{com.javacodegeeks.androidaccelerometerexample/com.example.lincision.SecondActivity}:      java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.lincision.SecondActivity cannot be cast to android.hardware.SensorEventListener
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 12:36:58.751: E/AndroidRuntime(18696): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.lincision.SecondActivity cannot be cast to android.hardware.SensorEventListener
```

Answer (score 3):

`SensorManager.registerListener` take `SensorEventListener`  object as parameter and you are not implementing `SensorEventListener` in `SecondActivity`.

Because you are implementing `SensorEventListener` in  `Accelerometer` so pass `acc` as first argument in registerListener :

```
sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener)acc, accelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Yes this was the error thank you but I get no output the textView shows nothing do you know what this could be ?

Comment: @BenBetzen: add log in `onSensorChanged` method then check method is called or not

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K I added log in the onSensorChanged and there i have an output so the error has to be in the SecondActivity but I have no idear where the error could be

Comment: I really have no idear

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.lincision.SecondActivity cannot be cast to
>   android.hardware.SensorEventListener

As the error says, you're casting Activity to SensorEventListener. This is the line that causes problem:

```
sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, accelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Don't cast **this** in registerListener to SensorEventListener, because **this** refers to SecondActivity, and it's not implementing SensorEventListener. Instead, pass **acc**, which is an object of Accelerometer implementing SensorEventListener, which in turn is the required first parameter to registerListener:

```
sensorManager.registerListener((SensorEventListener)acc, accelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Thanky yes I understand what you mean but if I write i how you told me I get that error messager:                                        The method registerListener(SensorEventListener, Sensor, int) in the type SensorManager is not applicable for the arguments 
 (SecondActivity, Sensor, int)

Comment: As @ρяσѕρєя K mentioned, pass the object of Accelerometer (acc) as the first argument, since it's implementing SensorEventListener. Updated my code too. +1 to ρяσѕρєя K answer though, as he was correct before me :)